# Android WorkManager is not responding to system time

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Basically, I am trying to use WorkManager to start job at specific time in the future (e.g. 24h or 1 week from now). I understand that WorkManager does not guarantee specific time, but that it will be close enough, which is OK for my case.

To start new job at specific time, I'm using `setInitialDelay(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Problem is that if system time changes (e.g. User manually sets another time, daylight saving time changes occurs, different timezone etc.), WorkManager will not increase/decrease delay time accordingly. This means that if user times goes one hour forward, my job will be executed one hour later then expected.

How to make WorkManager to be system time aware?

Comment: you want a job to be run at a specifically exact time in the future, regardless of the changes in system time?

Comment: Yes. If I set job to start at 5PM tomorrow, I don't want it to start at 6PM (in case that clock went 1 hour forward)

Comment: Android is notoriously unfriendly to such accuracies. you might be better off scheduling hourly or 2 hourly checks, and calling a web-based GMT epoch time service, to double check the exact timing you want, then recalibrate your next wake up time to actually execute the job accordingly.

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088873/why-use-the-onetimeworkrequests-setinitialdelay-function-of-the-workmanager